# What is the best practice for naming the id of XML Element in Android?

Tags: android, xml

I am not sure if anyone was bugged with this issue before, but it is one big pain for me.

How do you give an id to xml element in android?

Right now, I set the id with the pattern **[activity/fragment name][element type][specific name]**. For example, if I had an EditText to keep an email which is used in LoginActivity, I will give the id 'LoginEditTextEmail'.

The problem I'm facing is, with this approach, the id often ends up in a very long one.

How do you set the id? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 13):

Descriptive names are ideal (same as with the name to any variable in any programming language).

I think you have a good system already I would offer these potential ways to decrease the size of your IDs

**[activity/fragment name]** - Personally I would drop this, I tend to use one layout file per activity / fragment anyhow so there is no confusing what activity the view is meant to be in. Also there are times when I re-use some View widgets in multiple activities and I will leave them with the same ID so that the code to find and interact them is simplified (i.e. it can be copy/paste or put into a subclass of Activity)

**[element type]** - I use a 3 letter shorthand for the widget types:

- Edt = EditText
- Txt = TextView
- Lbl = TextView that is static for labeling something
- Btn = Button
- Prg = ProgressBar
- Lyt = Layout
- etc...

**[specific name]** - no real improvement to be made here, it has to be as long as it has to be to describe what it is for.

Comment: Thank @Tim, if I could leave the activity/fragment name, then it is best. I added that basically because I did not understand the id-lookup procedure well enough.

Comment: you certainly can leave it in =), I just personally tend to not use that.

Answer (score 6):

You're overcomplicating things. Just name it in whatever way is memorable to you. IDs only have to be unique per XML (i.e. you can have 50 different layouts with the id of `my_edittext`) since you find a view by it's ID only through a single view hierarchy.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank @kcoppock, if the id is needed to be unique only in a single view hierarchy, then it is clear to leave other chunks out. ; D

Comment: @kcoppock, does it become a problem for sibling fragments, or nested fragments?

Comment: Can be if you're looking for fragment views from the activity, but if you're doing all your view manipulation within the fragment (which you typically should) it won't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Much like naming anything, I tend to use the shortest name possible that accurately describes it. In the case of ids for layouts, just make sure each id is unique in your layout (you can reuse the same id in a different layout).

Answer (score 0):

Drop fragment, activity and type unless you qualify these in coding, so:

`boolean isLoggedIn = false;`

`android:id="@+id/is_logged_in"`

As mentioned in other responses the XML provides the qualifier, now you have to decide whether consistency and/or further qualification is necessary and if it befits.  Do you really need to qualify and if you don't is supporting the code going to be a lot harder by you or anyone else?

So what about `strings.xml`?

prefix the id with a frag or activity qualifier.  So, for example:

`<string name="profile_is_logged_in_true">Logged in.</string>`

`<string name="profile_is_logged_in_false">Not logged in.%</string>`

Also…

`<plurals name="plural_is_logged_in_duration">...`

I've *toyed* with:

`<string name="profile_isloggedin_false">Not logged in.</string>`

But not yet convinced.  This is actually a classification problem, now since solved in other disciplines by tagging.  Java provides dotted namespace and type qualifiers, so

`com.example.android.app.profile.State.isLoggedIn`

Android uses things like `R.string` :-)  So you have the Java plus some additional namespace from Android.  Don't forget you can have more than one string resources file, so perhaps:

`res/values/widget_defaults.xml`

could contain some default values for say a `TextView`.  The true and false strings should be handled by plurals - but the example hopefully helps, despite a tad contrived.